# File not downloading from secure website with HTTP POST

Tags: c#, http, networking, webbrowser-control

I am trying to download a pdf file from a web server over https in c# and getting HTTP OK response but file stream is not coming with response. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code behind:

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, ch, sec) => { return true; };


    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/GetReport");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.Accept = myRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
    myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
    myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.9");
    myRequest.Referer = "https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/Search";
    myRequest.UserAgent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36";

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content);
    myRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    Stream dataStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();        
    dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);          
    dataStream.Close();



    byte[] result = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
```

Downloading file from chrome is working fine and here is fiddler RAW http packet from browser:

```
POST https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/GetReport HTTP/1.1
Host: services.dps.ohio.gov
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 177
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://services.dps.ohio.gov
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/Search
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=t1nddo51g0jotl51cqev15rp; __RequestVerificationToken_L0NyYXNoT25saW5l0=iMy0lJ3OviGs0iXame8ebp8IdS6K9wpc8tFinYd0nhNnySTLlii-yHYU5tDJjv49Fqi29M_31mPiPdKWWtJJPWSmp4qGGvna9lW2rkDHUAs1

__RequestVerificationToken=eTJN31araRPeB-bhQaeU3awBDsCwR9BpkIYNqpsakTPRT1w1nXtbGFcfVRZS776ZW0NGv1aKahx3WJv5PNQ199iM7GF9Y9f7ws5KTG4gI3I1&id=NjgzMTIwOQ%3D%3D&btn_NjgzMTIwOQ%3D%3D=
```

This is my application's http packet:

```
POST https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/GetReport HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/Search
Accept-Language: en-GB,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: services.dps.ohio.gov
Content-Length: 177
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

__RequestVerificationToken=eTJN31araRPeB-bhQaeU3awBDsCwR9BpkIYNqpsakTPRT1w1nXtbGFcfVRZS776ZW0NGv1aKahx3WJv5PNQ199iM7GF9Y9f7ws5KTG4gI3I1&id=NjgzMTIwOQ%3D%3D&btn_NjgzMTIwOQ%3D%3D=
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with a tool like Telerik Fiddler (or WireShark). Then access the data you are after through a normal web browser while using Fiddler to monitor the details of the requests and responses between the browser and the server. With this knowledge, let your program precisely and completely mimic the the requests as sent by the web browser (i _really_ mean precisely and completely). Further use Fiddler to monitor what is going on between your program and the server and how the requests and responses possibly differ from what you saw when using a web browser...

Comment: @elgonzo I am already using fiddler to capture http packets and tried, only after that I decided to post question. Website requires https connection, is that causing any problem?

Comment: The Https resource you have in code is a Web Form that needs to filled to rquest informations. You're trying to download the Form content. You should probaly show what **`content`** actually contains, sinceit looks like you're trying to fill the Web Form. There are other issues: the Https resource needs a `SecurityProtocol` (usually Tls12) and validation callback to validate the server certificate and the code doesn't show any. `=> HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");`. Don't specify `br` because there's nothing in .Net that can handle it (...)

Comment: (...) Also, if you specify a content encoding, you need to set `[WebRequest].AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;`: the default is `none` and you'll get *garbage*. + Don't use `Encoding.Default`, `use Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi I will try adding security info to my header.

Comment: No header. Use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` and `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, ch, sec) => { return true; };`

Comment: Also, note that the Web Form has many hidden `<inputs>`. You need to pass them all, along with those that need to be filled with the elements in the selectors. + There's a `captcha`...

Comment: @Jimi Adding securityprotocol seems to have no effect and I am sending all hidden fileds in request body as shown in fiddler packet.

Comment: What *effect* are you referring to? As already asked: are you trying to fill in a Web Form to download specific informations that are the result of a query? If so, you hardly can achieve this: there's also a captcha to fill in in that WebForm. Using a WebBrowser, you can easily do it, since you have eyes. The `WebRequest` is instead totally blind. That's the reason why people insert captchas in their web pages: to avoid robot-downloads.

Comment: If you really, really want to do this, you need a good OCR that can identufy the characters in captcha Bitmap and a lot of patience in testing an training it to do the job. Before, verify whether they provide an API for this. Maybe they allow to request an identification token for remote queries.

Comment: @Jimi: Header does not contain any captcha, it contains a verification token and form and submit button id. I am sending all 3 fields.I am not thinking of automating captcha part.

Comment: Those informations are not sent with the Headers. It's a `x-www-form-urlencoded` post. The `urlencoded` part is the important one. See what it actually does.

Comment: @Jimi If you will navigate to website https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval, you have to input certain fields along with captcha. Then another page will load https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/Search. From this page I am trying to send webrequest for downloading files.

Comment: The second link you're referring to (first time I see it) returns: *The resource cannot be found.*. Btw, this is not the URI in your WebRequest: `(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval");`. You're not providing meaningful informations.

Comment: @Jimi: Second link requires captcha verification so it will not work without it. I request you please to go to url services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval and input cetain fields and captcha and then you will be navigated to second link. Please download a pdf file from Report column then only you will get final download link  https://services.dps.ohio.gov/CrashOnline/CrashRetrieval/OhioCrashReportRetrieval/GetReport.

Comment: You get to the result page only after you have filled in the Form. Captcha included.

Comment: @Jimi I am trying to create an application in c# with webbrowser control. Application will take captcha as input, navigate to second link and then start downloading all files from there.

Comment: If you want to automate this process in any way, you must have means to decode the Captcha. OCR can do it. There are examples around. As already said, you'll have to train the OCR. And suppose it will fail a lot of times anyway.

Comment: @Jimi Is it possible to manually input captcha(captcha is not at all a problem) and then start downloading pdf files over http? For now, this doesn't seem to be working even after providing all hidden parameters in http request.